# Finding out default DNS in OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, mac, dns, nslookup, dig

When doing "nslookup" on a windows machine you get the address of the default DNS you're using (http://gyazo.com/313d1ad31c1927741aa266fc7f8542fc), but for some reason you don't in OS X (http://gyazo.com/2b2474d84f6774f2ca00663ad3f23064). Is there any other way to **find out the default DNS from the Terminal**?

*Just a little sidenote: I don't use nslookup any more, I think the "host" command is much simpler and does the job cleaner. Perhaps there is a way to get the default DNS using "host"?*

Answer (score 4):

Just a note... as of 10.8 (Mountain Lion), the DNS resolver configuration is integrated into the mDNS responder code, so to see where queries go for various things, you have to run `scutil --dns` to find out the *actual* configuration.  Only the first DNS resolver is reflected in the standard **/etc/resolv.conf** file hence the comment in that file that it's no longer used by newer applications.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following on the terminal:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Thanks man! This output is a bit strange though: "# This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
# or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
# this Mac OS X system." Why does it say it's not the DNS used by most processes? @arpz

Comment: I apologise! It seems that it's actually changed since Snow Leopard (10.6). Now it's using mDNSResponder so you should look into that, I don't know any more than that, I'm afraid

Comment: Oh okay! You should upgrade ;) @arpz

Comment: Actually I run Mountain Lion but I'm not with my Mac at the moment :)

Comment: Ah okay, Mavericks is the latest though @arpz

Comment: I'm holding back on that because there's some audio stuff I use that isn't compatible yet afaik :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13371/discussion-between-axel-kennedal-techtutor-and-arpz)